# Mostrar hint apenas quando a aplicação é iniciada pela primeira vez

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe8

Possuo uma aplicação desktop que é um pouco complicada, então pensei em ajudar o usuário gerando imagens (Hints) para auxiliar no caminho.

Mas sei como isso é chato, então gostaria de saber se é possível que isso aconteça somente quando a aplicação é rodada pela primeira vez.

Poderia tentar fazer algo como Não mostrar essa dica novamente, mas não estou utilizando banco de dados... É possível fazer isso sem utilizar banco de dados?

Comment: Você pode salvar a informação em um arquivo INI ou no Registro do Windows. Tome o cuidado com a questão de permissões, se for salvar no INI prefira em uma pasta em que o usuário tenha total permissão. Já no caso do registro, deve usar a chave HKEY_CURRENT_USER... Ah, e não precisa fazer nada na mão, tem componentes gratuitos que lhe ajudam a fazer essa gravação de configurações, dê uma pesquisada. Abraço.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sim, da para fazer sem usar o Banco de Dados, basta gravar essa informação no Registro do Windows como mencionado no comentário do amigo @Paruba, podemos gravar na pasta do Registro `HKEY_CURRENT_USER`, vamos criar uma Pasta dentro dessa pasta com o nome do nosso sistema, e dentro dessa pasta vamos criar um registro com a informação desejada!

Função para Leitura do Registro:

```
function frmteste.LerRegistro: Boolean;
const
  vRaiz: String = 'Nome_Seu_Sistema';
var
  Registro: TRegistry;
begin
  Result := False;
  //Chama o construtor do objeto
  Registro := TRegistry.Create;
  with Registro do
  begin
    // Somente abre se a chave existir
    if OpenKey(vRaiz, False) then
    begin
      //Validando se ja abriu ou não...
      if ValueExists('Hint_Inicial') then
      begin
        if (ReadInteger('Hint_Inicial') = 1) then
          Result := True;
      end;
      // Fecha a chave e o objeto
      Registro.CloseKey;
      Registro.Free;
    end;
  end;
End;
```

Com esta função, você consegue saber se já abriu o Sistema alguma vez ou se é a primeira execução, isto pois no `Create` vamos implementar a gravação dessa informação:

```
procedure frmTeste.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
const
  vRaiz: String = 'Nome_Seu_Sistema';
var
  Registro: TRegistry;
begin
  {Se não encontrou o Registro, Cria o Registro informando...
  ...que ja mostrou o Hint Inicial}
  if (LerRegistro = False) then
  begin
    //Chama o construtor do objeto
    Registro := TRegistry.Create;
    { Abre a chave (se o 2°. Parâmetro for True, ele cria a chave caso ela ainda não exista.}
    Registro.OpenKey(vRaiz, True);
    //Aqui passamos 1 como parâmetro, 0 = nunca abriu 1 = ja abriu
    Registro.WriteInteger('Hint_Inicial', 1);
    //Fecha a chave e o objeto
    Registro.CloseKey;
    Registro.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Agora no `Show` do Formulário principal você implementa a leitura do Registro:

```
procedure frmTeste.FormShow(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if LerRegistro = False then
  begin
    {Aqui você chama o procedimento do Hint Inicial
    Chamada da função ou procedimento responsável pelo Hint Inicial.}
  end;
end;
```

No exemplo informado, a pasta do registro ficaria com a seguinte estrutura:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Nome_Seu_sistema\Hint_Inicial
```

**Edit:**

Ainda é possível efetuar a Leitura e Gravação em um arquivo de texto na raiz do seu sistema, bastaria usar uma TStringList no momento do `Show` do Form usando suas propriedades: `LoadFromFile` ou `SaveToFile`. Mas a Melhor opção e mais Profissional é usar o método que informei acima, gravar no Registro do Windows!

> Nota Importante: Sempre que gravar um valor no Registro do Windows, ao
>   Desinstalar seu Sistema não se esqueça de remover essa entrada! Assim
>   não fica lixo no Registro do Usuário!

Aguardo o Feedback!

Comment: Vou testar assim que possivel, após o carnaval e trago o feedback aqui..valeu :D

Comment: funcionou perfeitamente. obg.